# Query on Task.Phone?

Tags: apex, soql, polymorphic

It looks like querying Task 'phone' is NOT supported.  Can anyone confirm?

I can get Owner.Phone, but not read the phone field itself.

Acc. to [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=task_fields.htm&language=en_US):
Phone   Phone number of the contact or lead associated with the task. This field is automatically filled in with the value from the corresponding contact or lead record.

- Perhaps because it can't be queried because of the way sf is indexing it?

Please halp.

Comment: It's certainly odd that phone is listed as a standard Task field yet can't be queried directly.

Comment: did your first sentence mean to say "...is not supported."

Answer (score 3):

You might try using the WhoId's relationship (Who.) to get to it.

```
SELECT Id, Who.Phone FROM Task
```

Comment: When I tried querying for Who.Phone, it didn't error but does not give me the phone number back. If I change it to Who.Name I get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692742/how-to-get-email-from-task-object-record-using-soql), you will need to do two queries, one to get the task information and then one to get the contact/lead information. The phone field is not available in the schema in eclipse or when opening the object in the Developer console.
It looks like there is another option [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm), using TypeOf, but that would need to be enabled for your org by salesforce.

Comment: Phone is listed as a task standard field, yet the Query Editor in the Developer Console does not recognize it.

Comment: I was referring to the eclipse salesforce schema browser, but yes I do see it in the object field listing, but not when you open the object in the developer console.